# Https issue on 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

We have implemented https on our store a few months back and everything seems fine exceptive noted that the server response for htaccess 301 redirects don't seem to be honoring the https://

```
The server response is similar to this.

Location: http://www.example.com

Redirecting to: http://www.example.com
```

This is then leading crawlers to HTTP versions of the page then a 301 to the https version, creating a loop.

https is working on the front and backend fine except this 301 issue

Answer (score 0):

inspect your htaccess for any suspicious custom rewrite rules or redirects

Comment: Ive had a look there and cant find anything that would cause the conflict.

Comment: have you enabled https for frontend or only partially?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting the cookie setting in my CMS styem and this fixed my issue.